# A small sliver of moon rock

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs, noun-phrases

In the following sentences, does 'small' function as an adverb or an adjective?

> Visitors will be astounded at the amazing exhibits; one of these is a small sliver of moon rock that visitors are allowed to touch. The rock has been worn smooth by years of visitors reverently touching a piece of the moon.

(My students and I can't tell if 'sliver' or 'moon rock' functions as the noun/noun phrase... any help or reasoning much appreciated, this has been going around in my head for a week!)

Comment: "Small" modifies "sliver" or if you prefer, it modifies "sliver of moon rock."  At any rate, it's an adjective.  Then "of moon rock" is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: @JVL Not my downvote.

Comment: "A small sliver of moon rock" is a noun phrase, with the **noun** "sliver" as 'head'. "Moon rock" is also a noun phrase serving as complement of the preposition "of". In the preposition phrase "moon" modifies "rock".

Answer (score -1):

> **a small sliver of moon rock**

I think  the above is a noun phrase  and  small  is an adjective  qualifying  **sliver  of moon rock**..

Comment: It's a SLIVER (a thin piece), not 'a silver'.